# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, cakephp, warnings

Eu obtenho este erro:

> Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>   [CORE\Cake\Utility\Validation.php, line 490]

utilizando a action admin_upload_image, do meu controller Galleries. Mas esta action estava a funcionar correctamente, e eu não a modifiquei, a não ser colocar parâmetros para a validação do upload.

**Controller**

```
    public function admin_upload_image(){
        /*if(!$this->Session->check('Admin')) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Está a aceder a uma zona restrita. Por favor faça Login.');
            $this->redirect(array(
                            'controller' => 'admins',
                            'action' => 'login'));
        }*/
        $this->layout = 'admin_index';
        if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
          /*  $file = $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name'];*/
            $file = array(
                'GalleryImage' => array(
                'path' => $this->request->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']
                                        )
                );
            move_uploaded_file($this->data['gallery_images']['path']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/html/PushUp_app/app/webroot/img/gallery/' . $this->data['gallery_images']['path']['name']);

            $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
            $this->GalleryImage->create();
            if($this->GalleryImage->save($file)){
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ficheiro carregado com sucesso!'));
            }
            else{
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Erro ao carregar o ficheiro!'));
            }
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<h2>Adicionar Fotografia</h2>
<?php
    echo "<br>";
    echo $this->Form->create('GalleryImage',array('type'=>'file'));
    echo $this->Form->file('gallery_images.path');
    echo "<br>";
    //echo $this->Form->submit();
    echo $this->Form->end('Guardar');
?>
```

**Model**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class GalleryImage extends AppModel{
    //public $displayField ='path';
    public $useTable = 'gallery_images';
    //public $actsAs = array('MultipleDisplayFields' => array('fields' => array('path', 'id')));
    var $name= 'GalleryImage';
    var $validate= array(
        'path' => array(
            'rule' => array(
                'allowEmpty' => true,
                'extension', array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'tiff'),
                'fileSize', '<=', '40MB' 
                ),
            'message' => 'ERRO, a fotografia deve ter um tamanho inferior a 40MB.'
            )
    );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua variável **$validate** está declarando os *arrays* incorretamente. Faça assim:

```
var $validate = array(
    'path' => array(
        'rule' => array(
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'extension' => array('gif', 'jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'tiff'),
            'fileSize' => '40MB' 
        ),
        'message' => 'ERRO, a fotografia deve ter um tamanho inferior a 40MB.'
    )
);
```

Comment: O `'filesize' => '40MB'` faz com seja necessário ter um tamanho igual ou inferior a 40MB? No [livro](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html) do CakePHP aparece assim : `'rule' => array('fileSize', '<=', '1MB')`.

Comment: @SunT bom, o próprio CakePHP não tem um método de upload, talvez você deve estar usando uma biblioteca, ai tem que ver qual a especificação para isso. O que eu havia notado era a atribuição de um array, algo padrão do PHP.